# EADDRINUSE: address already in use when adding require

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

On request my server should execute a cmd command and deploy.js file. Everything works fine, but if I add this line `const { getSimpleMessage } = require('../src/server')` I get the error that port 3000 is already in use. Why is this happening?

Server.js:

```
app.post("/", (req,res) =>{ 
    console.log("Get from /"); 
    SimpleMessage = 'Hello world';
    exec('npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli',
        (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            console.log(stdout);
            console.log(stderr);
            if (error !== null) {
                console.log("v error")
                console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
            }
        });
    res.send("Server received the request");
                            });

// starting the server
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on port 3000');
});
```

Deploy.js:

```
const { getSimpleMessage } = require('../src/server');           //THIS LINE CAUSES ERROR

async function main() {
    const HelloWorld = await ethers.getContractFactory("HelloWorld");

    // Start deployment, returning a promise that resolves to a contract object
    const hello_world = await HelloWorld.deploy("HelloWorld");   
    console.log("Contract deployed to address:", hello_world.address);
 }
 
 main()
   .then(() => process.exit(0))
   .catch(error => {
     console.error(error);
     process.exit(1);
   });
```

I run the file with command: node src/server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `require('../src/server');` in `deploy.js` file, all code of the `src/server.js` part is run, including the part `app.listen(3000, ...)`. If the server is already running (using `node src/server.js` command) the port 3000 is already in use and running `deploy.js` (and thus attempting to run `app.listen(3000, ...)`) results in an error.

The simplest solution would be to separate the logic. If you want to keep both the `getSimpleMessage` and `app` declarations in the `src/server.js` file, you can remove the `app.listen` part from the file and instead export the `app` object. Then create e.g `index.js` file that imports the `app` object and runs the `app.listen` part.

`./index.js`:

```js
const { app } = require('./src/server');

// starting the server
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on port 3000');
});
```

However, I would suggest that more clean solution would be to just put `getSimpleMessage` function in a separate file (if possible).

Answer (score 1):

When the server is running and receives a `POST /` request, it deploys `Deploy.js`, which causes the

```js
app.listen(3000, ...)
```

command in `server.js` to be executed again, in another process. There would then be two processes both listening to port 3000, which leads to the observed error.

Perhaps you need to separate the `getSimpleMessage` function out of the `server.js` file.